# how to get id filed from json encode result

Tags: php, json, loops

I've this as a result from calling a function :

```
 json_encode(searchpage)
```

Result :

```
[{"category":"Hospital\/clinic","name":"\u05d1\u05d9\u05ea \u05d0\u05d1\u05d5\u05ea \u05e9\u05dc\u05de\u05d4 \u05d4\u05de\u05dc\u05da","id":"249739158463596"}]
```

how do i get to the id filed ?!

Comment: Get it where? In PHP code? If in PHP code, why would you `json_encode` it? (That gives you a string, whereas *before* using `json_encode`, you had an object you could access the properties of.)

Comment: ***sigh*** Another ask-and-run.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var temp = [{ "category": "Hospital\/clinic", "name": "\u05d1\u05d9\u05ea \u05d0\u05d1\u05d5\u05ea \u05e9\u05dc\u05de\u05d4 \u05d4\u05de\u05dc\u05da", "id": "249739158463596" }];
                alert(temp[0].id);
```